# Finalizer object in jmap histogram

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, finalizer, jmap

What can be the reason I am seeing 2k objects of java.lang.ref.Finalizer in my jmap histogram

154:          2224          88960  java.lang.ref.Finalizer

For Object.finalize() , Finalizer thread creates a new object everytime ?

Comment: Please See this first: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[What-topics-can-I-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: thanks for the valuable information @ankitsuthar